# How to write an linq statement to get the last of a group of records

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I have 2 SQL statements that basically do the same thing, that is, retrieve the last record from a table based on a datetime field for a group of records.  I am using the data-first Entity Framework model.  How would I write either of these SQL statements using LINQ Lambda functions?

ie,

```
var u = db.AccessCodeUsage.Where(...).GroupBy(...)
```

rather than

```
var u = from a in db.AccessCodeUsage
        where ...
        group by ...
```

SQL Statements:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    AccessCodeUsage a  
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT  1 
                    FROM    AccessCodeUsage 
                    WHERE   LocationId = a.LocationId
                    AND     Timestamp > a.Timestamp)

SELECT    a.*
FROM    AccessCodeUsage a
WHERE   a.Timestamp = 
        (SELECT MAX(Timestamp)
        FROM    AccessCodeUsage
        WHERE   a.LocationId = LocationId
        AND     a.AccessCode = AccessCode
        GROUP   By LocationId, AccessCode)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following which corresponds to the first SQL statement.

```
// Retrieve only the latest (greatest value in timestamp field) record for each Access Code
var last = AccessCodeUsages.Where(u1 => !AccessCodeUsages
                           .Any(u2 => u2.LocationId == u1.LocationId &&
                                      u2.AccessCode == u1.AccessCode &&
                                      u2.Timestamp > u1.Timestamp));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to have the method-call form, but are finding it tricky to work out, then use the other syntax first:

```
from a in db.AccessCodeUsage
  orderby a.TimeStamp descending
  group a by a.LocationId into grp
  from g in grp select g.First();
```

Then convert to method calls by taking each clause one at a time:

```
db.AccessCodeUsage
  .OrderByDescending(a => a.TimeStamp)
  .GroupBy(a => a.LocationId)
  .Select(g => g.First());
```

From which I can workout the second without bothering to write out the linq-syntax form first:

```
db.AccessCodeUsage
  .OrderByDescending(a => a.TimeStamp)
  .GroupBy(a => new {a.LocationId, a.AccessCode})
  .Select(g => g.First());
```

(Except it doesn't include what may be a bug, in that if timestamps aren't guaranteed unique, the SQL given in the question could include some extra inappropriate results).

I can't check on the SQL produced right now, but it should hopefully be equivalent in results (if not necessarily matching). There's cases where grouping doesn't translate to SQL well, but I certainly don't *think* this would be one.

Comment: Nice post, I had a similar problem but using anonymous types in GroupBy() as you have done allowed me to get what I needed.

Comment: Cool @PeadarDoyle. One piece of advice I'd give with `GroupBy()` is that if you aren't completely sure of how it'll be translated into a nice single query, it's always worth profiling how it works. Some uses can't be turned into just one query and the impact on db performance is horrible (and worse - it's often fine on test data and cripplingly bad on real data). In this example I'd say it *probably* should be good, but I'd check anyway...

Comment: If you *do* find the query is being turned into lots of SQL queries put a `.AsEnumerable()` before the `.GroupBy()`. Normally putting `.AsEnumerable()` into the middle of a db-backed Linq query results in worse performance (less work by the DB, more traffic from it, and more work by .NET), but those `.GroupBy()` that don't translate well are an exception where moving it to .NET at an earlier step in the process is a performance win (not a petty one either, can be the difference between too slow to be useful to too fast to notice).